# How to produce new dataframe by transforming given two dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, alignment

I have two different sized dataframes and i want to produce a new dataframe in the following manner.
Given dataframes are df1 and df2, and i want to produce df3 from df1 and df2.
But the hard part is i'm not able to getting any logic behind it. Any kind of help or hint is appreciable.

```
df1:
fname  start_time  end_time  
0_1          0.0       5.6       
1_0          5.6       8.0       
2_1          8.0      10.4       
3_0         10.4      13.6       
4_1         13.6      18.4       
5_0         18.4      24.8       
6_1         24.8      28.0       
7_0         28.0      32.0       
8_1         32.0      35.2       
9_0         35.2      42.4       
10_1        42.4      44.8       
11_0        44.8      48.0       
12_1        48.0      48.8       
13_0        48.8      52.0   

df2:
fname  start_time  end_time
 0        0.21      6.99
 1        7.98     13.65
 2       13.92     16.92
 3       17.04     19.65
 4       20.01     21.96
 5       22.65     25.14
 6       25.35     28.71
 7       28.86     35.10
 8       36.75     39.30
 9       39.75     41.40
10       41.40     45.12
11       45.30     46.68
12       47.73     49.83

df3:
fname  start_time  end_time
 0       0.21         5.6
 1       5.6          6.99
 2       6.99         7.98
 3       7.98         8.00
 4       8.00         10.4
 5       10.4         13.6
 6       13.6         13.65
 7       13.92        16.92
 8       17.04        18.4
 9       18.4         19.65
....... and so on.
```

I am able to get it when the df's are of same shape by comparing df1['end_time'] with df2['start_time'] and df2['end_time']. But not been able to figure out when the df's are of different shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a dictionary can be created for each dataframe (here it is df1 and df2) and update the dictionary into the df3.